# split string into sentences keeping new line separator

Tags: python, string, nltk

let's say I have a string like:

```
s = "Hello world. Hello world.\n\n This is foo.\n Goodbye world."
```

I am currently separating this string into sentences by `.` using

```
 from nltk import tokenize
    sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(s)
sentences = ['Hello world.', 'Hello world.', 'This is foo.', 'Goodbye world.']
```

I need to do some subtitutions in each sentence, something like this:

```
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    if "world" in sentence:
        sentences[i] = sentence.replace("world", "internet")
    if "foo" in sentence:
        sentences[i] = sentence.replace("foo", "me")
```

But if after separating them I want to join them again, and keep the line separators `\n`, the output is not correct

```
ss = " ".join(sentences)
print(ss)
Hello internet. Hello internet. This is me. Goodbye internet.
```

This should be the correct output:

```
Hello internet. Hello internet.

 This is me.
 Goodbye internet.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just change `ss = " ".join(sentences)`

to `ss = "\n".join(sentences)`